# Why is my JS Loop overwriting previous entries in my object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, loops

So I have an object, that I'm using in nodejs. It looks as such:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var sUser = x[i];
            mUsers[sUser.userid] = CreateUser(sUser);
            ++mUsers.length;
        }
```

So I'm pulling information from an external source, and it breaks down as an array full of instances of this:

```
[{ name: 'Michael Lovesllamas Lankford',
 created: 1338420951.11,
 laptop: 'pc',
 laptop_version: null,
 userid: '4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057',
 acl: 0,
 fans: 1,
 points: 5,
 avatarid: 34 }]
```

and so forth.

so that information is passed as x in the above function.

```
global.mUsers = {length:0}

global.UserBase = {
    userid: -1,
    name: "noidea",
    isSuperUser: false,
    isDJ: false,
    laptop: "pc" };

process.on("registered", OnRegistered);

global.OnRegistered = function(a) {
        //misc code here
        RegisterUsers(a.users);
        //misc code here
}

global.CreateUser = function(a) {
    var b = UserBase;
    b.userid = a.userid;
    b.name = a.name;
    b.laptop = a.laptop;
    if (a.acl > 0) b.isSuperUser = true;
    return b;
};

global.RegisterUsers = function(x) {
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var sUser = x[i];
            mUsers[sUser.userid] = sUser;
            ++mUsers.length;
        }
```

}

Now, I've logged it in the loop, and mUsers[sUser.userid] does indeed = sUser.
but when I console.log(mUsers) immediately after the loop, I get this:

```
{ 
 userid1: { userid: userid3, name: name3, item: item3 },
 userid2: { userid: userid3, name: name3, item: item3 },
 userid3: { userid: userid3, name: name3, item: item3 }
}
```

And I don't know why it's overwriting. Any ideas?

Comment: do you really mean `++i` and not `i++` their both quite different, when applied in `for` loops.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What does `CreateUser` do?

Comment: I do mean i++, and I meant to remove CreateUser, let me edit this.

Comment: @DaltonGore ok next can you verify `x` is what you expected it to be?

Comment: I just edited it, and that is the full function that is not working. The first bit is an actual log of what is coming through with x, but with a few more [it varies]

Also the problem seems to be with CreateUser, as when I just did mUsers[sUser.userid] = sUser; it came out just fine. >: I'm so sorry if I'm being confusing T_T

Comment: Just checked again, it's definitely the CreateUser function. Is there anything wrong with it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @DaltonGore `var b = UserBase;` this doesn't seem right you seem to be continuously referencing the same object, unless im mistaking, you might need to call `Object.create` or `Object.spawn` to create a new copy, this might help http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance

Comment: @samy.vilar I am referencing the same object. Basically UserBase is a template object, and CreateUser grabs said template, and then edits the values with the information supplied, and then returns it.

Comment: @DaltonGore yes but its the same object each time, every time you edited, and call it again, it still remembers the previous values that where set, since its being `reference` unless nodejs does some magic, as such it will retain the last values set which will referenced by all the other objects, which is why you are getting that weird behavior AFAIK, can you try `var b =  Object.create(UserBase);`

Comment: @samy.vilar yes, I just tried wrapping it in that, and I'm still getting the duplication. EDIT: Actually, it did work, but now it's butchering UserBase. Instead of an edited object, I'm getting this: '4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057':
   { userid: '4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057',
     name: 'Michael Lovesllamas Lankford',
     laptop: 'pc' },
Which is nice, but it's not the full UserBase.

Comment: @DaltonGore did you really updated it, cause once you add that line it works http://jsfiddle.net/zGRaR/1/

Comment: @DaltonGore look at `__proto__` all the previous templates are still there, just call them and you'll get a proper response, `mUsers[1212].isSuperUser` anyway let me write up an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you where continuously referencing the same object when you where calling CreateUser, as such it was simply updating and returning a reference which was being kept through out all the calls, this is why when you where printing it, it just printed the last update. 
You need to create a copy of the object.

```
global.CreateUser = function(a) {
    var b = Object.create(UserBase); // this will create a copy of it.
    b.userid = a.userid;
    b.name = a.name;
    b.laptop = a.laptop;
    if (a.acl > 0) b.isSuperUser = true;
    return b;
};
```

now CreateUser is actually creating a copy, when you go through the properties the default ones may not appear right away, but theres still there, they've being simply moved to `__proto__` you can still call them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below it is working for me

```
var obj = {
            userid1: { userid: "userid1", name: "name3", item: "item3" },
            userid2: { userid: "userid2", name: "name3", item: "item3" },
            userid3: { userid: "userid3", name: "name3", item: "item3" }
        };

var muser = {};

for (var key in obj) {
    muser[key] = obj[key];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have misinformed all of you. I'm going to edit it with a better example. But the original is not an object, it's an array

Comment: I modified object to array and it is working for me pls see below pseudo code var obj = [
             { userid: "userid1", name: "name1", item: "item1" },
             { userid: "userid2", name: "name2", item: "item2" },
             { userid: "userid3", name: "name3", item: "item3" }
        ];



var muser = {length:0}

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    
    muser[obj[i].userid] = obj[i];
    ++muser.length;
}

for (var key in muser) {
    
    var obj  = muser[key];
    for (var key1 in obj) {
        alert(obj[key1]);
    }
}